# Can someone check what is happening with insertatend function.. it is not creating all the blocks mentioned in the main function

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

I added print statement in the if else loop of insertatend and inertatfront function, this resulted in printing the printf statement everytime i called both function from main... but in display it is not displaying all values. I think maybe the nodes are broken somewhere while calling... See the output below the code. It shows only three values, while it should be showing all the values that I have entered in main().
Here is my code..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int value;
    struct node* ptr;
};

struct node* insertatend(struct node* h, int value)
{
    struct node* newnode;
    newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newnode->value = value;
    newnode->ptr = NULL;

    if (h == NULL)
        return newnode;
    else {
        while(h->ptr!=NULL)
        h=h->ptr;
        h->ptr = newnode;
        return h;
    }
}

struct node* insertatfront(struct node* h, int value)
{
    struct node* newnode;
    newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    if (h == NULL) {
        newnode->value = value;
        newnode->ptr = NULL;
        return newnode;
    }
    else
    {
        newnode->value = value;
        newnode->ptr = h;
        return newnode;
    }
}

void display(struct node* h)
{
    while ((h->ptr) != NULL)
    {
        printf("The value stored in the block is %d\n", h->value);
        h = h->ptr;
    }

    if (h->ptr == NULL)
        printf("The value stored in the block is %d\n", h->value);
}

void main()
{
    struct node* head;

    head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    head = insertatend(head, 90);
    head = insertatend(head, 30);
    head = insertatfront(head, 5);
    head = insertatend(head, 12);
    head = insertatend(head, 1);
    head = insertatfront(head, 25);
    display(head);
}
/* Output:The value stored in block is 25
 * The value stored in block is 5
 * The value stored in block is 1
 */
```

Comment: It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: Thanks UnlikePluto!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Major mistakes you seem to be making in your code :

1) modifying the `head` pointer in the insert function. This statement in `insertatend` :

```
while(h->ptr!=NULL)
    h=h->ptr;
```

changes the head of the list itself. Instead, you should be using a different pointer to traverse till the end.
Change `insertatend` to :

```
struct node* insertatend(struct node* h, int value)
{

    struct node* newnode;
    newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newnode->value = value;
    newnode->ptr = NULL;

    if (h == NULL){
        h=newnode;

    }
    else {
        struct node *temp;
        temp=h;
        while(temp->ptr!=NULL) temp=temp->ptr;
        temp->ptr = newnode;
    }
    return h;
}
```

2) The case where `h` is NULL will never happen as you have already malloced for `head` in `main`. Remove statement `head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));` from `main`